# How to dynamically prepare a selector for matching with respondsToSelector

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, respondstoselector

Given a class with a property such as:

`@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString* un_conventional;`

I tried forming a selector like so:

```
SEL setterMethod =
  NSSelectorFromString(
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@", [key capitalizedString]]
  );
if ([customer respondsToSelector:setterMethod]) {
    //do something
}
```

PS: Just take it for granted that `key` is a variable with the value `un_conventional`

The problem seems to be that this doesn't match the correct setter method because `capitalizedString` causes `setterMethod` to be named `setUn_Conventional` instead of `setUn_conventional` ... the letter "c" is also capitalized!

So does anyone have any suggestions on how to dynamically prepare a selector for such a scenario such that it results in a selector named `setUn_conventional` and can be used to match via respondsToSelector?

Comment: Can I at least get a reason for the down-vote?

Comment: Probably because this kind of meta-programming is an anti-pattern and indicative of serious potential architecture issues (Wasn't me, though, I'd as soon just answer the question).   Or, potentially, because the person meant to suggest that you should likely look into Key-Value Coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SEL setterMethod = NSSelectorFromString(
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
          @"set%@%@",
          [[key substringToIndex:1]uppercaseString],
          [key substringFromIndex:1]
    ]
);
```

would do the trick if you can guarantee that key is at least 1 character long.